# Get currentuser from local with firebase/auth (beta 9)

Tags: firebase, web, firebase-authentication, beta

Firebase/auth currently in version 9 stores by default the session locally inside indexedDB. But I can't find a method within firebase to retrieve the local session when loading the application.
[image]

[onAuthStateChanged](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start#set_an_authentication_state_observer_and_get_user_data) takes time to get the auth ready when it should be possible to retrieve the "saved current user session".

```js
auth.onAuthStateChanged(function (userData) {
  if (userData) {
    // User is signed in.
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

Is there a method to access the local current user directly without accessing manually to the indexedDB? rather than dumpling the indexedDB like in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/Matt-Jensen/d7c52c51b2a2ac7af7e0f7f1c31ef31d), or sending the user to localStorage myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably looking for this:

```
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
const user = auth.currentUser; // null if no user
```

You can find more information in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user)